# Sinatra: DB Authentication with Sessions

Tags: ruby, sinatra, authlogic

I am writing a small sinatra application that I am integrating with Authlogic (following https://github.com/ehsanul/Sinatra-Authlogic-Template)

Everything works except for when I try to login. I get the following error:

```
NameError at /login
undefined local variable or method `active' for #<User:0x000001040208f0>
```

I am including the authlogic gem versus including it as a vendor. So my Sinatra app is not exactly the same as the one on Github.

Any and all inquiries will be MUCH appreciated!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found out my issue.

Here is the model according to the Github page:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    # Bcrypt is recommended
    #crypto_provider = Authlogic::CryptoProviders::BCrypt
    c.perishable_token_valid_for( 24*60*60 )
    c.validates_length_of_password_field_options =
     {:on => :update, :minimum => 6, :if => :has_no_credentials?}
    c.validates_length_of_password_confirmation_field_options =
     {:on => :update, :minimum => 6, :if => :has_no_credentials?}
  end

  def active?
    active
  end

  def has_no_credentials?
    crypted_password.blank? #&& self.openid_identifier.blank?
  end

  def send_activation_email
    Pony.mail(
      :to => self.email,
      :from => "no-reply@domain.tld",
      :subject => "Activate your account",
      :body =>  "You can activate your account at this link: " +
                "http://domain.tld/activate/#{self.perishable_token}"
    )
  end

  def send_password_reset_email
    Pony.mail(
      :to => self.email,
      :from => "no-reply@domain.tld",
      :subject => "Reset your password",
      :body => "We have recieved a request to reset your password. " +
               "If you did not send this request, then please ignore this email.\n\n" +
               "If you did send the request, you may reset your password using the following link: " +
                "http://domain.tld/reset-password/#{self.perishable_token}"
    )
  end
end
```

I removed all of the mail methods but my script was failing on the `active?` method because it was looking for an active column in the users table. Since I am unable to append this column to the table (due to data integrity with another system) I simply told my method to `return true`

My User.rb

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic do |c|

  end

  def active?
    return true
  end
end
```

Hope this helps someone!